# How do I add background color under background image?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I need a background color underneath where my background image disappears on my mobile version. Instead, all I get is white space. I've tried everything I can think of. I think I'm exhausted, and I just need some fresh ideas.

Any help is appreciated!

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="vidContainer">
    <video autoplay loop poster="assets/bgVideo.mp4" id="bgvid">
    <source src="assets/bgVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="assets/bgVideo.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="mailto:info@confidential.com">
        <img id="logo" src="assets/img/logo-black.png"/>
    </a>
    <a href="mailto:info@confidential.com" style="text-decoration:none">
        <p id="bigData">Big Data. Big Ideas.</p>
    </a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    if (screen.width <= 800) {
        document.getElementById("vidContainer").innerHTML = "";
    }
//-->
```

CSS:

```
body, html{
max-width: 100%;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
body{
 background-image: url("http://i710.photobucket.com/albums/ww108/benkelsey/mobileBG.png");
background-color: black;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
height:100%;
}
#logo{
margin-top:13em;
display:block;
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
height:35em;
padding-left:19px;
padding-top:7px;
}
#bigData{
text-align:center;
font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
font-size:2em;
color:black;
text-shadow: -1px 0 white, 0 1px white, 1px 0 white, 0 -1px white;
padding-bottom:0;
margin-bottom:0;
}
video#bgvid{
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
-moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
-ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
-o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
z-index: -100;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean where your background video disapears?  What div do you want the background color in? It doesn't look like you're trying to insert a background color anywhere else than in your body tag.

Comment: No, I mean where the background image disappears. My JavaScript makes the video not appear on mobile. Instead, a background image appears, but it doesn't fill the whole height of the browser. It gets cut off and leaves white space underneath.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle or codepen? Also, is that all the JS you're using? Is them image getting cut off or the div/body?

Comment: @BenKelsey How about adding `html {height:100%;}`?

Comment: I'm with Zac, show us an example. I can't replicate your problem.

Comment: @sdcr I believe you are right

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think you have to put the background-color before the background-image. Because the image is there, so I think your explorer don't recognize the background-image property.. I don't know.. That was my first thought.